# RuntimeError: Unable to open ./dlib_model/shape_predictor_68_face_landmarks.dat

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, face-recognition, dlib

I'm following an online course, but I met a problem.
The error message:

`self.ldmark_detector = dlib.shape_predictor('./dlib_model/shape_predictor_68_face_landmarks.dat')
RuntimeError: Unable to open ./dlib_model/shape_predictor_68_face_landmarks.dat`

The code:

`class Face_detector(QtCore.QThread):
    def __init__(self, textBrowser):
        super(Face_detector, self).__init__()
        self.face_detector = dlib.get_frontal_face_detector()
        self.ldmark_detector = dlib.shape_predictor('./dlib_model/shape_predictor_68_face_landmarks.dat')
        self.face_info = {}
        self.textBrowser = textBrowser
        self.detecting = True  # flag of if detect face
        self.ldmarking = False  # flag of if detect landmark
        self.total = 0`

I literally had no clue what happened. I installed dlib but I searched in my machine, there is neither a folder called `"dlib_model"` nor a file called `"shape_predictor_68_face_landmarks.dat"` But the code should be right.

By the way, I installed dlib by using `pip install dlib`. It seems it stored in a weird position, but my program can import dlib successfully. And my current interpreter is `user/bin/python2.7`

`Collecting dlib
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/05/57/e8a8caa3c89a27f80bc78da39c423e2553f482a3705adc619176a3a24b36/dlib-19.17.0.tar.gz
Building wheels for collected packages: dlib
  Running setup.py bdist_wheel for dlib ... done
  Stored in directory: /home/huiting/.cache/pip/wheels/50/b6/b5/5f46aacfd18028ff57591cfb53fcc7554362977c15e9060e67
Successfully built dlib
Installing collected packages: dlib
Successfully installed dlib-19.17.0`

Answer (score -1):

You need to download this file "shape_predictor_68_face_landmarks.dat".

Comment: Please post the answer with description and code snippet, i.e where to change as part of user question.